# How does React re-use child components / keep the state of child components when re-rendering the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, every time a component is rendered/re-rendered, it regenerates all of it's child nodes/components using `createElement`. How does React know when to persist the components state between re-renders?

As an example, consider the following code:

```js
class Timer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { seconds: 0 };
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState(state => ({ seconds: state.seconds + 1 }));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  render() {
    return createElement('div', null,
      'Seconds: ',
      this.state.seconds
    );
  }
}
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { clicks: 0 };
  }
  click() {
    this.setState(state => ({ clicks: state.clicks + 1 }));
  }
  render() {
    return createElement('button', { onClick: () => this.click() },
      createElement(Timer, null),
      'Clicks: ',
      this.state.clicks
    );
  }
}
render(createElement(Button, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can try this code with the Preact REPL [here](https://preactjs.com/repl?code=Y2xhc3MgVGltZXIgZXh0ZW5kcyBDb21wb25lbnQgewogIGNvbnN0cnVjdG9yKHByb3BzKSB7CiAgICBzdXBlcihwcm9wcyk7CiAgICB0aGlzLnN0YXRlID0geyBzZWNvbmRzOiAwIH07CiAgfQogIHRpY2soKSB7CiAgICB0aGlzLnNldFN0YXRlKHN0YXRlID0%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%2BICh7IGNsaWNrczogc3RhdGUuY2xpY2tzICsgMSB9KSk7CiAgfQogIHJlbmRlcigpIHsKICAgIHJldHVybiBjcmVhdGVFbGVtZW50KCdidXR0b24nLCB7IG9uQ2xpY2s6ICgpID0%2BIHRoaXMuY2xpY2soKSB9LAogICAgICBjcmVhdGVFbGVtZW50KFRpbWVyLCBudWxsKSwKICAgICAgJ0NsaWNrczogJywKICAgICAgdGhpcy5zdGF0ZS5jbGlja3MKICAgICk7CiAgfQp9CnJlbmRlcihjcmVhdGVFbGVtZW50KEJ1dHRvbiwgbnVsbCksIGRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkpOwo%3D).

Notice that when the button is pressed and the clicks value is updated, the state of the `Timer` component persists and is not replaced. How does React know to re-use the component instance?

While this may seem like a simple question at first, it becomes more complex when you consider stuff like changing the props passed to a child component or lists of child components. How does React handle changing the props of a child component? Does the child component's state persist even though it's props have changed? (In Vue, the state of a component does persist when it's props change) How about lists? What happens when an entry in the middle of a list of child components is removed? A change to a list like that would obviously generate very different VDOM nodes, yet the state of the components still persists.

Comment: `createElement` does not create a new component. It returns a description (a `ReactElement`) which component to render in that place, with what properties and children. This is what react uses to determine whether the component tree changed.

Comment: That's useful to know, I'm currently reading through React's source code to better understand how their VDOM implementation works.

Comment: If you find any insights about their diffing algorithm (especially about when elements are considered "the same" vs not), please make sure to [post an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - I'm curious as well

Comment: *"When a component updates, the instance stays the same, so that state is maintained across renders. "* https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#component-elements-of-the-same-type

Comment: @FelixKling I think the OP knows that, the question is what React considers as an update and what as a new component.

Comment: @Bergi: I think the linked site explains that? If after any change the type of the component is still the same, it's an update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `createElement` vs `render` vs mount

When a React Component such as your `Button` is rendered, a number of children are created with `createElement`. `createElement(Timer, props, children)` does not create an instance of the `Timer` component, or even render it, it only creates a "React element" which represents the fact that the component *should* be rendered.

When your `Button` is rendered, [react will reconcile](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) the result with the previous result, to decide what needs to be done with each child element:

- If the element is not matched to one in the previous result, then a component instance is created then mounted then rendered (recursively applying this same process). Note that when `Button` is rendered for the first time, all of the children will be new (because there is no previous result to match against).
- If the element is matched to one in the previous result, then the component instance is reused: its props are updated, then the component is re-rendered (again, recursively applying this same process). *If the props did not change, React might even choose not to re-render as an efficiency.*
- Any elements in the previous result that was not matched to an element in the new result will be unmounted and destroyed.

## React's diffing algorithm

An element "matches" another one if React compares them and they have the same type.

The default way for React to compare children, is to simply iterate over both lists of children at the same time, comparing the first elements with each other, then the second, etc.

If the children have `key`s, then each child in the new list is compared to the child in the old list that has the same key.

See the [React Reconciliation Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) for a more detailed explanation.

## Examples

Your `Button` always returns exactly one element: a `button`. So, when your `Button` re-renders, the `button` matches, and its DOM element is re-used, then the children of the `button` are compared.

The first child is always a `Timer`, so the type matches and the component instance is reused. The `Timer` props did not change, so React might re-render it (calling `render` on the instance with the same state), or it might not re-render it, leaving that part of the tree untouched. Both of these cases would result in the same result in your case - because you have no side-effects in `render` - and React deliberately leaves the decision of when to re-render as an implementation detail.

The second child is always the string `"Clicks: "` so react leaves that DOM element alone too.

If `this.state.click` has changed since the last render, then the third child will be a different string, maybe changing from `"0"` to `"1"`, so the text node will be replaced in the DOM.

---

If `Button`s `render` were to return a root element of a different type like so:

```js
  render() {
    return createElement(this.state.clicks % 2 ? 'button' : 'a', { onClick: () => this.click() },
      createElement(Timer, null),
      'Clicks: ',
      this.state.clicks
    );
  }
```

then in the first step, the `a` would be compared to the `button` and because they are different types, the old element and all of its children would be removed from the DOM, unmounted, and destroyed. Then the new element would be created with no previous render result, and so a new `Timer` instance would be created with fresh state, and the timer would be back at 0.

---

| `Timer` matches? | previous tree | new tree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no match | `<div><Timer /></div>` | `<span><Timer /></span>` |
| match | `<div>a <Timer /> a</div>` | `<div>b <Timer /> b</div>` |
| no match | `<div><Timer /></div>` | `<div>first <Timer /></div>` |
| match | `<div>{false}<Timer /></div>` | `<div>first <Timer /></div>` |
| match | `<div><Timer key="t" /></div>` | `<div>first <Timer key="t" /></div>` |

Answer (score 1):

Never used Vue, but this is my take.

> Does the child component's state persist even though it's props have changed? (In Vue, the state of a component does persist when it's props change)

This depends on how you handle the props in your child.

This child will re-render every time you change (mutate) your props.

```
const Child = (props) => {
    return <div>{ props.username }</div>;
};
```

This child will not re-render when props change since the return value is dependent on the local state, and not the props.

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(props.username);
    return <div>{ state }</div>;
};
```

This child will re-render when props change, as local state updates with the new props.

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(props.username);

    useEffect(() => {
        // changing props changes the component's state, causing a re-render
        setState(props.username); 
    }, [props]);

    return <div>{ state }</div>;
};
```

As seen in the examples above, the programmer is the one in control of whether React triggers a re-render of a child.

> How about lists? What happens when an entry in the middle of a list of child components is removed? A change to a list like that would obviously generate very different VDOM nodes, yet the state of the components still persists.

When a list of children is involved (eg. when `.map` is used) React will require the [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) parameter, so that React will be aware what was add/removed/changed between parent component re-renders.
React requires that the same key be used for the same components to prevent unnecessary re-renders (don't use `Math.random()` as your key).

Comment: "*This child will not re-render when props change since the return value does not depend on the prop*" - how would react know? I'd assume it still calls the component's `render` method (or calls the component function), even if it won't update the DOM because the VDOM stays the same.

Comment: it changes base on state. You can put a console.log() inside the child state to see if it re-renders. It will call the console.log when it re-renders